# In multiple paging systems, how is the secondary page table loaded into real memory

Tags: operating-system, paging

Assuming that primary and secondary tables exist in multiple paging systems, assuming that the size of the secondary page table is 16 bytes and the size of the page that can be loaded is 16 kB, the maximum space required to load a program with a size of 20 kB into actual memory is 20 kB + 16 bytes of the secondary page table? Or is it 20kB + 16kB? Ignore the primary page table.

I thought the size of the 2nd page table would load into memory, but Im confused about what happens to the space if 2nd page is used and internal fragmentation occurs.